# How to hide text input in terminal

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm writing a script in Bash that prompts the user for a password and I need the typed text to not show, as when you enter an ssh password.

Does anyone have the solution for this?

Comment: [Same question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980668/how-to-get-a-password-from-a-shell-script-without-echoing)

Comment: /Which/ password?  If the password is being captured solely to be passed into some other utility program, there may be better ways of providing it!

Answer (score 22):

You may add `-s` to your `read` command (you are not providing it, so I suppose you are using `read -r`), so it would become:

```
read -r -s password
```

From `read --help`:

> ```
> -r    do not allow backslashes to escape any characters
> -s    do not echo input coming from a terminal
> ```

Comment: Also avoid stripping leading and trailing whitespace: `IFS= read -rs password`

Answer (score 10):

In order for the terminal not to show typed text, `echo` needs to be turned off.  The command `stty -echo` does this.  To return to normal, run `stty echo`.

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "Enter password: "
stty -echo
read -r password
stty echo
echo ""
echo "password=$password"
```

If, due to a typo or other error, the script fails to restore echo, run `reset` to recover.

The above script, including the use of [stty](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1p.html) and [read](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html), is POSIX compatible.  This means it will work with both `bash` and `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Is `read -s` SIGINT safe? I frequently find myself resorting to `stty sane` after Ctrl-Cing badly-behaved programs, and this script could get wedged in `-echo`.

Comment: I like this answer for older systems that don't have a modern bash - worked well for me.